# Android saving data from edit texts fields to database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to SQLite. I have an activity in which I have different fields like Name,Email,Date of Birth etc. When user fill the information and clicks the save button I want it to get saved to the database. But I am stuck in mid way and don't know what to do.How to save the data from Edit Text Views to the database on Save Button click.Please help me.
I am sharing my code.

DataBaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NewUserDb.db";
    private static final String TABLE_INFO = "info";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_GOAL = "userGOAL";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "userName";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "userEmail";
    public static final String COLUMN_DOB = "userDOB";
    public static final String COLUMN_HEIGHT = "userHeight";
    public static final String COLUMN_WEIGHT = "userWeight";
    public static final String COLUMN_GENGER = "userGender";;
    public static final String COLUMN_ZIP = "userZIP";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_GOAL,
            COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_DOB, COLUMN_HEIGHT,
            COLUMN_WEIGHT, COLUMN_GENGER, COLUMN_ZIP };

    // http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial

    /*
     * public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory
     * factory, int version) { super(context, name, factory, version); // TODO
     * Auto-generated constructor stub
     * 
     * }
     */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE User ( "
                + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "gaol TEXT, "
                + "name TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");

        // create fresh books table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void addUser(NewUserDb newuserdb) {
        // for logging
        // Log.d("addBook", book.toString());

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_GOAL, newuserdb.getGoal()); // get title
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, newuserdb.getName()); // get author
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, newuserdb.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_DOB, newuserdb.getDob());
        values.put(COLUMN_HEIGHT, newuserdb.getHeight());
        values.put(COLUMN_WEIGHT, newuserdb.getWeight());
        values.put(COLUMN_GENGER, newuserdb.getGender());
        values.put(COLUMN_ZIP, newuserdb.getZip());

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_INFO, // table
                null, // nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column
                            // values

        // 4. close
        db.close();
    }

    public NewUserDb getNewUserDb(int id) {

        // 1. get reference to readable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // 2. build query
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_INFO, // a. table
                COLUMNS, // b. column names
                " id = ?", // c. selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                null, // e. group by
                null, // f. having
                null, // g. order by
                null); // h. limit

        // 3. if we got results get the first one
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        // 4. build book object
        NewUserDb newUserdb = new NewUserDb();
        newUserdb.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        newUserdb.setGoal(cursor.getString(1));
        newUserdb.setName(cursor.getString(2));
        newUserdb.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
        newUserdb.setDob(cursor.getString(4));
        newUserdb.setHeight(cursor.getString(5));
        newUserdb.setWeight(cursor.getString(6));
        newUserdb.setGender(cursor.getString(7));
        newUserdb.setZip(cursor.getString(8));

        // Log.d("getBook("+id+")", book.toString());

        // 5. return book
        return newUserdb;
    }

    // Deleting single book
    public void deleteUser(NewUserDb newuserDB) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. delete
        db.delete(TABLE_INFO, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(newuserDB.getId()) });

        // 3. close
        db.close();

        Log.d("deleteBook", newuserDB.toString());

    }

}
```

NewUserDb.java

```
public class NewUserDb {

    private int id;
    private String goal;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String dob;
    private String height;
    private String weight;
    private String gender;
    private String zip;

    public NewUserDb() {
    }

    public NewUserDb(int id, String goal, String name, String email,
            String dob, String height, String weight, String gender, String zip) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.goal = goal;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.zip = zip;
    };






    public int getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }

    public void setGoal(String goal) {
        this.goal = goal;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", goal=" + goal + ", name=" + name
                + ", email=" + email + ", dob=" + dob + ", height=" + height
                + ", weight=" + weight + ", gender=" + gender + ", zip =" + zip

                + "]";

    }

}
```

AccountActivity.java

```
public class AccountActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText et_weight, et_height, et_email, et_dob, et_name;
    private Button btn_uploadPhoto, btn_shootPhoto, btn_del, btn_save;
    private Switch genderSwitch;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    private String year;
    private String month;
    private String day;

    DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.accounts);

        btn_shootPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_uploadPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn_del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_del);
        btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        et_dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_dob);
        genderSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
        et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_height);
        et_height.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        et_weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_weight);
        et_weight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                      //what to do here ??
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: what is your problem in doing?? there is many samples in goolge, check all and ask if you feel any specific problem

Comment: unable to understand , what to do so that data will get saved to database on save button click

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you declare database create table query string in your DatabaseHelper class like this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_USER = "create table UserInfo("
        + "_id VARCHAR(20)," + "userGOAL VARCHAR(20),"
        + "userName VARCHAR(20)," + "userEmail VARCHAR(20),"
        + "userDOB VARCHAR(20)," + "userHeight VARCHAR(10),"
        + "userWeight VARCHAR(10)," + "userGender VARCHAR(10),"
        + "userZIP VARCHAR(10) "+ ")";
```

Then write inside onCreate method of DatabaseHelper

```
db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_USER);
```

Then declare object of SqliteDatabase and DatabseHelper in your AcountActivity like this:

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
```

Afer this write following code inside your button onClick method:

```
dbHelper= new DatabaseHelper(ActountActivity.this);
db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
insertValues.put("_id", "User_Id");
insertValues.put("userGOAL", "User_Goal");
insertValues.put("userName", "User_Name");
insertValues.put("userEmail", "User_Email");
insertValues.put("userDOB", "User_DOB");
insertValues.put("userHeight", "User_Height");
insertValues.put("userWeight", "User_Weight");
insertValues.put("userGender", "User_Gender");
insertValues.put("userZIP", "User_Zip");

db.insert("UserInfo", null, insertValues);
db.close();
```

May this help you.

Comment: do i have to remove any of the written code ?

Comment: and also please tell me, how I am getting the each edit text data ??

Comment: Its basic procedure for inserting data in sqlite database if you want to implement other logic its depend on you.

Comment: Get values from edit text by using like this et_name.getText().toString();

Comment: i am doing this .. String a = et_name.getText().toString() String b = et_email.getText().toString() etc etc .. and how will i save the data of this a and b in database ??

Comment: Simply replace insertValues.put("userName", "User_Name"); and
insertValues.put("userEmail", "User_Email"); by insertValues.put("userName", a); and
insertValues.put("userEmail", b);

Comment: just one last ques... say i entered name = ABC and save it. ABC will get saved to the database now when i restart the app, will the abc be visible to the edittext ?

Comment: No, If you want to show user name in edit text after Rebooting your app you need first retrieve data from database then set those data within your edit text like et_name.setText("user_name");

Comment: yes i want to show user name in edit text

Comment: yes sure .. just one thing more, what is this varchar(20) or varchar(10) means ?

Comment: Its shows how many max character you insert in database at specified column

Answer (score 0):

try `.getText()` on your EditText
like `yourEditText.getText();` and set it into your NewUserDb and pass the NewUserDb object into addUser method of your DatabaseHelper class